# Flutter moving UI Elements

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, flutter, flame

I am trying to develop a UX that would have a center and intractable objects move towards the center. Similar to a circular space invaders, but I want these objects to be buttons. Currently I am using flutter but I wanted to ask if there any libraries that I can use to develop this? I am thinking flame and box 2D right now but I dont want to work myself into a corner. Are there other ways of constantly updating the position of UI objects?

Thank you for any advice!

[image: Simple Image of what im trying to make]

Comment: Why do you want the objects to be buttons?
It would be a lot easier to use a BodyComponent or SpriteComponent in Flame.

Answer (score 1):

Flame doesn't allow you to easily have widgets moving around as components inside a flame game. You can render widgets on top of your flame game but you will have to control their movement yourself, which can be taxing.

However, if you can let go of the idea of using flutter Buttons, you can definitely have a game with clickable objects moving around exactly how you want, and you can control their appearance through the render method.

Hopefully that answers your question!